# mongodb - is it possible to filter after an $elemMatch projection in a find query?

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like this in a collection called 'variants':

```
{
    "_id" : "An_FM000900_Var_10_100042505_100042505_G_A",
    "analysisId" : "FM000900",
    "chromosome" : 10,
    "start" : 100042505,
    "end" : 100042505,
    "size" : 1,
    "reference" : "G",
    "alternative" : "A",
    "effects" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Analysis:FM000900-Variant:An_FM000900_Var_10_100042505_100042505_G_A-Effect:0",

            "biotype" : "protein_coding",
            "impact" : "LOW",
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Analysis:FM000900-Variant:An_FM000900_Var_10_100042505_100042505_G_A-Effect:1",

            "biotype" : "protein_coding",
            "impact" : "MODERATE",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find documents in that collection that meet some criteria ("analysisId":"FM000900"), and after that I want to project over 'effects' array field to bring just the first element in 'effects' array that meet some criteria ("biotype" : "protein_coding" and "impact" : "MODERATE").

The thing is that I just want to show the main 'variant' document if and only if at least one element in the 'effects' array has meet the criteria.

With the following query I get the expected result except that I get 'variant' documents with 'effects' array field empty.

```
db.getCollection('variants').find(  
{
     "analysisId":"FM000900"
}
,
{ 
    "effects":{
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "biotype" : "protein_coding",
            "impact" : "MODERATE"
        }
    }
}     
).skip(0).limit(200)
```

Can somebody transform this query to only get 'variant' documents with some element in 'effect' array after the projection if possible?

Can it be done in another way, without using aggregation framework if possible? as the collection has millions of documents and it has to be performant.

Thanks a lot, guys!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [$elemMatch as query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in addition of your projection, it will filter variants that have at least one effects array element that match all conditions. 
So  your query will be :

```
db.getCollection('variants').find(  
{
     "analysisId":"FM000900",
     "effects":{
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "biotype" : "protein_coding",
            "impact" : "MODERATE"
        }
    }
}
,
{ 
    "effects":{
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "biotype" : "protein_coding",
            "impact" : "MODERATE"
        }
    }
}     
).skip(0).limit(200)
```

In addition, a [compound multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#compound-multikey-indexes) that covers both query and projection can improve reading performance, but use it carefully as it can drastically reduce writing performances.